# How to update an Item in ElasticSearch

Tags: elasticsearch, nest

How to update an item in elasticsearch. I know there are ways to re index or update whole document but i don't want to do that. I just have to update only a single entry.Can u please tell me how to do that in elastic search using NEST.

Comment: I think what you're looking for is called `partial update` in elastic search. http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/partial-updates.html

Comment: Are you looking to update a single property in a document? Then you may want to look at updating using [scripts](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/partial-updates.html#_using_scripts_to_make_partial_updates)